# Google cloud storage object deletion with google cloud API, Node.js, and request.del()

Tags: node.js, api, google-cloud-storage

As the title is saying, I'm currently trying to delete a object using request, and google_API.

But, [Even though I did what Google Cloud Platform said,](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oOwB2.png)

[It doesn't work.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oBvre.png)
Please, Help me. what should I do?

Comment: Please add your source code as text here.

Comment: Please click the blue hyperlink text :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't appear you're providing any sort of authentication token. You are providing an API key, which is important when making anonymous requests, but an API key does not authenticate your identity or grant any permissions. I am guessing that you are getting 403 Forbidden responses.

Since you're using Node.JS, I might suggest trying the [google-cloud](https://googlecloudplatform.github.io/google-cloud-node/#/) library. It's easy to use, and it deals with OAuth 2 authorization logic for you. A delete might look like this:

```
var gcloud = require('google-cloud')({
  projectId: 'grape-spaceship-123'
  keyFilename: '/path/to/keyfile.json'
});

var gcs = gcloud.storage();
var myBucket = gcs.bucket('backups');
var myFile = myBucket.file('someFile.png');
myFile.delete(function(err, apiResponse) {});
```